# How to "select DISTINCT" many tables in oledb in vb.net

Tags: sql, select, distinct, oledb, dbf

I wanted to do the sql command "select DISTINCT" but it didn't work if there was another solution. I have four tables namely GSDTS, GSGTS, STFTS and TEMPTABL.

Thanks

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBRRj.png)

```
 Private Sub PopulateComboBox()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GSDTS"
        Try
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
                    'Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)

                    'Insert the Default Item to DataTable.
                    Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

                    row(0) = ""
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)

                    'Assign DataTable as DataSource

                    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
                    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "PNM"
                    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "PNM"
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you neeed to cnage the query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GSDTS
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GSGTS
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM STFTS 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM TEMPTAB
ORDER BY PNM
```

the DISINCT will only take UNIQUE OMN and the UNION will take care of all duplicates.

But you will so never know,. which PMN belongs to which table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is an error I updated the screenshot in this post

Comment: that depends on the databse you are using try parenthesis aroung the selects

Comment: `ORDER BY PMN` here's the problem there is a typo